# Run shell command on Azure Linux VM from PowerShell

Tags: linux, powershell, hyper-v, azure

I have a Linux server on Microsoft Azure. It's an Ubuntu 14 Server. Apparently, I've done something wrong with the UFW (firewall) configuration and now I can't ssh into machine at all. I need to disable the firewall to get back into machine. I assume the only option I have now is to try to do it via PowerShell since Azure doesn't provide any KVM access.

Is this possible? How can I execute a shell command via PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to run commands on an Azure VM from outside the VM itself; there also is no VM console access. This is a really big limit in Azure, unfortunately.

If you accidentally lock yourself out of a VM, the only way to recover it is by downloading its virtual disk and running it on a local Hyper-V server, where you can get console access and fix whatever is wrong; or, if the problem can be fixed offline (f.e. by editing a configuration file), you can attach the disk to another Azure VM and work on it from there.

Comment: This isn't completely accurate. You can Delete the VM in question, while preserving the vhd, and attach the vhd to a healthy, running Linux VM, to get access to the disk.

Comment: That's the second option I mentioned ("you can attach the disk to another Azure VM and work on it from there").

Comment: Ah. Reading comprehension issues this morning...

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed the [custom script extension](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/20/automate-linux-vm-customization-tasks-using-customscript-extension/), you may use it to disable or configure your firewall.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** @massimo already answered this (and I didn't realize he covered the attach-disk solution). But, since I already typed this up, I'll leave the answer here, since it contains a bit more detail about attaching a disk from a locked-out VM...

---

To access your VM's disk if you're locked out, you can delete the Virtual Machine (but ***not*** delete the disk/vhd or any attached disks), which breaks the lease on the page blob holding the vhd. Then, you should be able to attach the vhd to a running Linux VM as an attached disk. At this point, you should be able to access the files on the disk.

I don't know anything about the firewall config and if you'll be able to alter it this way, but at least you'll have file-level access.

Answer (score 1):

Azure provides an [extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-vmaccess-reset-password-or-ssh/) to recover access to Linux VMs in many scenarios. Jointly with custom script, as @proteus mentioned, you should be able to fix this without recreating the VM.